# Prepare a pipeline that will archive all home directory files that are more than a month old

Tags: unix, pipeline, tar

I did this and it's wrong.

```
find $HOME | -type f -mtime +30 | tar -rvf myarchive.tar
```

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44891885/3776858) and remove `-maxdepth 1` from answer.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.